# Plotting Point Data in Cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I have displayed a one dimensional NetCDF dataset using Cartopy/Matplotlib, and want to display values of this data at specific points on the map (formatted in lat,lon), as shown in the following example image:

[image: Example image with data plots]

I have sifted through Matplotlib/Cartopy documentation, and believe that the pyplot.plot function is the solution. The line of code that I expect to run this process would be plt.plot(x coordinate, y coordinate, data). Am I on the right track, or is there a more effective solution?

Answer (score 1):

I advise taking a look through the visualisation types of matplotlib. There is a short course which does precisely this at http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SciTools/courses/blob/master/course_content/notebooks/matplotlib_intro.ipynb?create=1 that you might find useful.

In particular, when it comes to plotting point data `plt.plot` is a good option. When it comes to showing *lots* of point data, you will probably want to look at `plt.scatter`.

When you want to visualise a *field* of data, you will probably want `plt.contourf` and `plt.pcolormesh` for filled contours and block plots.

You may also be interested in tools that simplify the process of handing the metadata on your behalf. [XArray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) gives you a convenient multi-dimensional dataset with a slick interface, [Iris](https://github.com/scitools/iris) gives you a conventions based datamodel that understands things like coordinate systems and units (disclosure: I am one of the authors of Iris).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, apologies for the delayed response. I have been able to plot a point on the map, however the data from the gridded dataset I'd like to have plotted with this lat/lon point is not showing up. The code can be found here (https://imgur.com/k2Tn7gN) and the corresponding image produced here (https://imgur.com/9sgrNfe). Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out pelson's answer, but to cut it short, yes, you can use any matplotlib plotting function, simple use `ax.plot(...)` on the axes handle `ax`. Note that you should always include the `transform=cartopy.crs. ...` argument (it is part of the GeoAxes object `ax`) to make sure you're in the right projection.

Comment: Appreciate you getting some feedback on this! I have been able to plot a point on the map, however the data from the gridded dataset I'd like to have plotted with this lat/lon point is not showing up. The code can be found here (https://imgur.com/k2Tn7gN) and the corresponding image produced here (https://imgur.com/9sgrNfe). Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have additional questions, you may want to edit your original question with a minimal working example (copyable) to get more feedback.